# Store sessions on idle and use specific name for each stored session

Tags: doom, session

I usually have multiple instances of doom emacs running (one for every project).

I use this line in my config to save the session of each instance after 10 seconds idle time.

```
(run-with-idle-timer 10 t #'doom-save-session)
```

This leaves me with a bunch of stored session:

```
> ls -la ~/.emacs.d/.local/etc/workspaces

.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:48 autosave
.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:48 autosave1
.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:44 autosave2
.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:44 autosave3
```

Now the problem is, that I can't see which session belongs to which project.

Does anyone know how I can use a better template for the filenames? E.g.: `auto--PROJECT_ROOT_DIR--NUMBER`:

```
.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:48 auto--home-peter-projects-foo--1
.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:48 auto--home-peter-projects-bar--1
.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:44 auto--home-peter-projects-foo--2
.rw-r--r-- 39k peter 16 Jun 19:44 auto--home-peter-projects-bar--2
```

Answer (score 0):

Got my feet wet with lisp and hacked this code togehter. It works fine so far:

```lisp
;; Save project session on 10 sec idle
(run-with-idle-timer 10 t #'project-save-session)

;; and every 180 sec, period
(run-at-time 180 t #'project-save-session)

;; Save session with project root dir in file name:
(defun project-save-session ()
  (setq base_path "/home/peter/.emacs.d/.local/etc/workspaces/auto--")
  (setq project_root (directory-file-name (projectile-project-root)))
  (setq project_root_escaped (replace-regexp-in-string "/" "-" project_root))
  (setq full_path (concat base_path project_root_escaped))
  (doom/save-session full_path))
```